# How do I make this python code populate my sql table with new information that it's pulling from a "live" feed?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, spyder

I have a python scrip that pulls "live" or historical data from yahoo finance. I am trying to make the data that is being pulled automatically import into a SQL table in my local db. The code for pulling the data is as follows:

```
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period='5y', interval='1d')
```

I tried to incorporate it into the following code below so that it would import into my SQL table, but I'm not sure it's correct since it's not populating anything. How can I fix this code up?

```
import pyodbc 
import yfinance as yf

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=LOCALHOST1234'
                      'Database=LOCALHOST1234;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
               INSERT INTO Historical_Data' (Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume)
               VALUES 
               (df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period='5y', interval='1d')
                ''')
conn.commit()
```

I updated my code to the below but I get the following error

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

I'm not sure what this means?

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=localhost1234;'
                      'Database=localhost1234;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
    
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period='5y', interval='1d')
df.to_sql('Historical_Data', conn)
```

Comment: You are trying to have your SQL Server execute Python code.  Of course it doesn't work.  And since you're not checking for errors, you didn't see the synta error.  You need to fetch the `yf` data, then convert that into a list of records, then use `executemany` instead of `execute`, and put substitution marks (`VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)` or `VALUES (?,?,?,?...)`).  Alternatively, pandas has a `to_sql` method.

Comment: Thanks for the information. For the substitution marks that you mention, is that simply a place holder for the values that it is being pulled from the yf code? Just a bit confused since most of the guides I looked at seem to be hard coding the values into SQL tables using the INSERT INTO function.

edit: also for fetching the yf data, would it be the same as using the print(df) so that it populates the data?

Comment: error suggests that it connected to `Microsoft SQL Server` but it sends SQL for `SQLite`. And doc for [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) suggests that connection has to use `SQLAlchemy` or it will use `SQLite`.

Comment: @furas Thank you. I thought that to_sql was a pandas command? Do you know how I can fix this code to make it write to my sql table? I'm using SSMS

Comment: `to_sql` is pandas command but it uses `SQLAlchemy` to work with database. Probably you would have to install and use `SQLAlchemy` to create connection to `SSMS` - see [Microsoft SQL Server — SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html) and [PyODBC in SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc)

Comment: There is an example of how to `INSERT` a row in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15#insert-a-row).

Comment: Also SSMS is an IDE, it's not a database engine. SQL Server is the database engine.

Comment: Thanks for the link and clarification @Larnu

Comment: I just tried copying the directions on that documentation link you sent, but I'm getting errors: Undefined name 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' (pyflakes E)

Comment: *"Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'"* is quite the specific error; the object (`sqlite_master`) doesn't exist in the default schema in the database you are connected to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what any of this means. Very new to Python.... is the error because the code df.to_sql is a command that you can only with sqlite/sqlalchemy? Do you know what the code should be to import the results from df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period='5y', interval='1d') into the table Historical_Data?